Was Einstein aware of Newton-Cartan theory?
Did Einstein know that Newtonian gravity could be described using spatial curvature while formulating General Relativity? I know that Newton-Cartan was formally developed after GR, but I find it hard to believe that Einstein was completely unaware of the strong parallelism.

You find it hard to believe that Einstein was unaware in 1915 of something that appeared in 1923???

He may not have come across Newton-Cartan, but he'd seen Interstellar.

@conifold Reading the question, I am not getting the impression that it is asked if Einstein knew of the work before it appeared, but rather if Einstein knew of it at all, after it appeared. This later reading of the question is answerable. See my answer.

@Conifold I was not asking if He knew about NC before it was published. I was asking if, in 1915, He knew about the very basic idea it stems from, that Newtonian gravity can be described using curvature. Having this intuition is a very long way from developing NC formally.

@GeorgEssl (can tag only one user for each comment)

@Lucens I have edited my answer.

Einstein published an early popularization of the ideas of General Relativity  in a newspaper (Vossische Zeitung, 26 April 1914). Einstein writes (see Collected Papers Vol 6. Doc 1):

In recent years it has turned out that such an extension of relativity
theory can be carried out, and that it leads to a general theory of
gravitation which contains the Newtonian theory as a first
approximation. According to this theory, light rays suffer a curvature
in a gravitational field; though minute, it is just within the range
of astronomical measurement

Later in another book-length popularization he writes (Einstein, A. On the Special and General Theory of Relativity
(A Popular Account), Vieweg (1917) (see Einstein Collected Papers Vol 6 Doc. 42)):

This acceleration or curvature corresponds to the influence on the
moving body of the gravitational field prevailing relatively to K'. It
is known that a gravitational field influences the movement of bodies
in this way, so that our consideration supplies us with nothing
essentially new.
However, we obtain a new result of fundamental importance when we
carry out the analogous consideration for a ray of light.

(Emphasis is mine)
Einstein in early popularization of GR emphasizes curvature in context of light as he sees that as the novel effect differing from Newton's gravity, but clearly he equates curvature and acceleration in this exposition.
There is little doubt that he understood this on a technical detail level and understood that he was modeling curvature in differential geometry, but I will omit this here.

Below part of the answer was written in response to the original formulation of the question. I'll leave it here because it might have independent interest to someone searching for information even on the current question. Also it is still responsive to the title of the question if not the body.
Elie Cartan and Einstein exchanged letters on the topic between 1929 and 1932, initiated by Cartan who brought his papers of 1923-1925 at the Annates de I'Ecole normale on affine connections and absolute parallelism to Einstein's attention.
The letters in original and English translation can be found in:

Robert Debever (ed.) (1979). Elie Cartan and Albert Einstein: Letters
on Absolute Parallelism, 1929-1932. Princeton University Press.

Hence Einstein clearly knew of Cartan's work on what in his terminology was "Fernparallelismus" (see his A. Einstein, Riemann-Geometrie mit Aufrechterhaltung des Fernparallelismus, Sitzungsber. Berlin 1928, XVII, p. 217–221.)
Quite early on in the exchange, in a letter dated the 25th of August 1929, Einstein writes (Debever's translation from German):

Please forgive my long silence. This has been caused by many doubts as
to the correctness of the course I have adopted. But now I have come
to the point that I am persuaded I have found the simplest legitimate
characterization of a Riemann metric with distant parallelism that can
occur in physics. I am now writing up the work for the Mathematische
Annalen and would like to be permitted to add yours to mine as we have
agreed.

Indeed Einstein and Cartan would end up publishing one paper each, back to back, in the same issue of the Mathematischen Annalen in 1930:

Einstein, A. (1930). Auf die Riemann-Metrik und den Fern-Parallelismus gegründete einheitliche Feldtheorie. Mathematische Annalen, 102(1), 685-697.
Cartan, E. (1930). Notice historique sur la notion de parallélisme
absolu. Mathematische Annalen, 102(1), 698-706.

